# Why do some citizens support authoritarian regimes?

Tags: government, power

Why is it that across the world, some people consider authoritarian regimes to be beneficial. Why is this, and why is there a rise on support for authoritarian regimes. Source; http://www.journalofdemocracy.org/sites/default/files/Foa%26Mounk-27-3.pdf

Comment: " why is there a rise on support for authoritarian regimes"  you will want to source that for this question to be meaningful.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as too broad, because it is unanswerably broad.

Comment: @twelth: there's plenty of newspaper commentary on such a rise for this to not require sourcing, it's meaningful as it stands; though adding sources is generally useful.

Comment: @Drunk Cynic: there's a book by Pankaj Mishra that addresses this question: *The Age of Anger*, and no doubt there are others; and this means that useful answers are possible.

Comment: @SaraHassan could you provide at least one example?  Generally, people think they're getting A, when they end up with B.  If you know an example, ask your question with the example.

Comment: @MoziburUllah If it takes a book to answer this question, and likely there are books with different conclusions than the first book, this question is certainly too broad for SE.

Comment: @Drunk Cynic: but nonetheless answerable; it merely requires (some) people to read books as opposed to newspaper or internet commentary; perhaps your standards are a little low? Remind me, just how long this SE has been in beta.

Comment: @MoziburUllah There are many books on the topic, going back to at least Hobbes' *Leviathan* (but there are probably earlier examples). At the very least the question should clarify what exactly it means with "authoritarian regimes", as that's very open to interpretation at the moment. There are many differences between different authoritarian regimes (e.g. Putin's Russia isn't North-Korea which isn't Stalin's Russia which isn't Suharto's Indonesia, etc.).

Comment: @MoziburUllah To the contrary, my standards are high. I've done formal research in Constitutional Law, Systems Engineering and Analysis, Political Science, and Military Policy/Strategy. This question is overly broad: across the world requires an examination into the development and growth of disparate cultures; the claim that some people consider authoritarian regimes beneficial requires validation; the claim there is a rise in support for authoritarian regimes requires proof. This is doctorate level sociological, geopolitical, anthropological work.

Comment: Voted to close due to being broad enough that there's bodies of literature on the topic.

However, in general the only way a populace of a country will support an authoritarian regime is radical nationalism, which is usually temporary and tied to the living conditions in the country. Other than that, those who benefit from authoritarianism will of course support it and the general populace who do not benefit either fall into line or fall into a gulag.

Comment: @Drunk Cynic: I'm not convinced; there's one useful answer already.

Comment: Please don't point to an entire issue of a journal as a reference.  Please identify the quote that you believe establishes that there is a rise in authoritarianism.  At minimum this should include the title of the article/paper and the author.  It's better if you copy the text of the quote and/or include page numbers.

Comment: Here's [one perspective](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2017/nov/10/how-colonial-violence-came-home-the-ugly-truth-of-the-first-world-war) on the recent rise of populism as a political force that you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question and would benefit from a source being added with respect the the "rise of support for authoritarian regimes". For the purposes of this answer the assumption will be such a trend is not forced and is based on the potential perceived benefits of authoritarianism.

In order to narrow this down a little so that the question is not too broad this answer will consider democracy as the primary alternative to an authoritarian government.

Some of the possible potential benefits of such as regime/ the potential drawbacks of democracy

- More democratic governments tends to be slow at getting things done due to the existence of checks, balances and processes there may well be a perception that authoritarian governments can get things done faster
- Democracy only really works well when the electorate are engaged properly with the process, well informed and there is a strong press to hold politicians to account. In many places these conditions don't exist so the benefits of democracy may not be fully realised.
- Authoritarianism can offer strong and clear leadership for the country a consistent plan and a vision. Other forms of government may be offer inconsistent or unclear views depending on who is in power .
- A leader who has long term prospects can provide stability that regular government/ministerial changes can not
- Democratic systems can have issues with the representation of those sections of the population that aren't the target demographic of the main political parties (or the ones that are in power) an authoritarian leadership may take a more balanced approach to maintain popular support (a number of democratic systems can allow governments to rule with less votes than their opposition)

**Note:** This isn't about saying that authoritarianism is a better or worse form of government it is simply about considering the possible arguments in favour of such a system

Comment: If people think: "How could anyone support an authoritarian government?" Just use the example of Net Neutrality. No matter which side you favor, all can agree that it is the government who will enforce it with the power of Law Enforcement and Judicial Vengence based on whatever standard they feel it should have.  The power will even reside with people who will never be elected (FCC).  Yet plenty think this power better resides in the government.